# Why are non-sendable properties mutable from Tasks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, task, sendable

A lot of online resources say non-final classes are not Sendable by default. That means classes and their properties are not thread-safe. So why is this code not raising an error:

```swift
class Counter {
    var count = 0
    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

class Tester {
    var counter = Counter()
    
    func mutate() {
        Task {
            counter.increment()
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting an error to be raised at `counter.increment()` since `counter` isn't Sendable.

Can anyone tell why this code isn't raising an error?

Comment: Ints are safe across threads https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.5/sendable

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes but `counter` is a reference type, making it non-Sendable. Since I'm capturing `counter` in the Task I would expect an error to be raised.

Comment: It doesn't matter that counter is a reference type. You are modifying an integer property of it and integers are thread safe.  Try making `Counter` a struct and make `increment` a mutating function and see what happens.  Now you have a value type, which is not sendable.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried that and it still compiles without an error

Comment: @Paulw11 - A mutable `Int` property in a `class` is *not* thread-safe just because `Int` is a `Sendable` type. Turn on “strict” concurrency checking and the compiler will warn you of these issues.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting an error/warning because, as of Xcode 14.3, at least, the compiler will only perform “minimal” checks re `Sendable`. So, set the “Strict Concurrency Checking” setting to “Complete”:

[image]

Next, the first problem with your code snippet at this point is really that `Tester` is not `Sendable`:

[image]

But let’s assume that you get past that, either by making `Tester` a `Sendable` type or simply capture the `Counter`, rather than `Tester`. Then the compiler will report the `Sendable` problem, this time regarding `Counter`:

[image]

---

So, you asked:

> online resources say non-final classes are not `Sendable` by default

Yes, classes are not `Sendable` by default.

> That means classes and their properties are not thread-safe.

To be more precise, it just means that you have not informed the Swift concurrency system whether it is thread-safe or not. It might be. It might not be. (In this case, it is not.) You simply do not get `Sendable` inference for free, even if it was internally thread-safe, as you would with a `struct` or `actor`.

Specifically, if a class is `final` and has no mutable properties, it is generally thread-safe, but is not automatically `Sendable`. But you can just add `Sendable` conformance to let the compiler know that it really is. However, if the class has some mutable properties and you want to mark it as `Sendable`, you have to manually make it thread-safe with some manual synchronization mechanism for its mutable properties and, then, when you are done, you can mark this class as `@unchecked Sendable` to let the compiler know that although the compiler cannot reasonable verify whether it is really `Sendable` or not, but that you are vouching for it.

But, in short, your online resources are correct and classes are not `Sendable` by default. You just need to bump up the “Strict Concurrency Checking” setting in order to see all these `Sendable`-related warnings.

---

While I suspect you know this, for the sake of other readers, we can demonstrate the lack of thread-safety with a unit test:

```swift
import XCTest

class Counter {
    var count = 0

    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

final class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {
    func testThreadSafety() async throws {
        let iterations = 10_000_000
        let counter = Counter()

        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 0 ..< iterations {
                group.addTask { counter.increment() }
            }
        }

        let count = counter.count
        XCTAssertEqual(count, iterations)     // testThreadSafety(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("9957759") is not equal to ("10000000")
    }
}
```

Or turn on [TSAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/#Detect-data-races-among-your-apps-threads), and it will produce:

```
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: Swift access race (pid=70115)
  Modifying access of Swift variable at 0x00010619a690 by thread T4:
    #0 (1) suspend resume partial function for closure #1 @Sendable () async -> () in closure #1 (inout Swift.TaskGroup<()>) async -> () in MyAppTests.MyAppTests.testThreadSafety() async throws -> () <null> (MyApp2Tests:arm64+0x1fc0) (BuildId: b3c1129a1404328b97d6c213879bfa2832000000200000000100000000010d00)
    #1 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) <null> (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:arm64e+0x404c0) (BuildId: a4a1be62f3953ce897049a710004921e32000000200000000100000000000b00)

  Previous write of size 1 at 0x00010619a690 by thread T1:
    #0 (1) suspend resume partial function for closure #1 @Sendable () async -> () in closure #1 (inout Swift.TaskGroup<()>) async -> () in MyApp2Tests.MyAppTests.testThreadSafety() async throws -> () <null> (MyApp2Tests:arm64+0x1fec) (BuildId: b3c1129a1404328b97d6c213879bfa2832000000200000000100000000010d00)
    #1 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) <null> (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:arm64e+0x404c0) (BuildId: a4a1be62f3953ce897049a710004921e32000000200000000100000000000b00)

  Location is heap block of size 24 at 0x00010619a680 allocated by thread T5:
    #0 __sanitizer_mz_malloc <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64+0x5e244) (BuildId: b4e4be85d92a32d7a3e9edbe68feb69132000000200000000100000000000b00)
    #1 _malloc_zone_malloc_instrumented_or_legacy <null> (libsystem_malloc.dylib:arm64e+0x20c1c) (BuildId: fa535b0545933a7893d77bcff7431df632000000200000000100000000020d00)
    #2 swift::runJobInEstablishedExecutorContext(swift::Job*) <null> (libswift_Concurrency.dylib:arm64e+0x404c0) (BuildId: a4a1be62f3953ce897049a710004921e32000000200000000100000000000b00)

  Thread T4 (tid=18485890, running) is a GCD worker thread

  Thread T1 (tid=18485880, running) is a GCD worker thread

  Thread T5 (tid=18485893, running) is a GCD worker thread

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: Swift access race (/…/MyAppTests:arm64+0x1fc0) (BuildId: b3c1129a1404328b97d6c213879bfa2832000000200000000100000000010d00) in (1) suspend resume partial function for closure #1 @Sendable () async -> () in closure #1 (inout Swift.TaskGroup<()>) async -> () in MyAppTests.MyAppTests.testThreadSafety() async throws -> ()+0x60
==================
```

But if you either add manual synchronization of the mutable variable, `count`, in `Counter`, or just make it an actor, the data race is resolved and it is thread-safe. E.g.:

```swift
actor Counter {
    var count = 0

    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

final class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {
    func testThreadSafety() async throws {
        let iterations = 10_000_000
        let counter = Counter()

        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 0 ..< iterations {
                group.addTask { await counter.increment() }
            }
        }

        let count = await counter.count
        XCTAssertEqual(count, iterations)     // success!
    }
}
```